How to use Measure as Slicer in Power BI
I have a measure, i want to filter it with a slicer with under stock, over stock In 'Table' visual , optimum , how to do it in Power BI
StockStatus = 
VAR Department = SELECTEDVALUE('3_month_sales_&_stock'[Department])
VAR StockHoldingDays = '3_month_sales_&_stock'[StockHoldingDays]

RETURN
IF(
    ISBLANK(StockHoldingDays),
    "",  -- Return blank if StockHoldingDays is blank
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        Department = "Kids", IF(StockHoldingDays > 120, "Over Stock", IF(StockHoldingDays < 90, "Under Stock", "Optimal Stock")),
        Department = "Ladies", IF(StockHoldingDays > 120, "Over Stock", IF(StockHoldingDays < 90, "Under Stock", "Optimal Stock")),
        Department = "Mens", IF(StockHoldingDays > 120, "Over Stock", IF(StockHoldingDays < 90, "Under Stock", "Optimal Stock")),
        Department = "Footwear", IF(StockHoldingDays > 120, "Over Stock", IF(StockHoldingDays < 90, "Under Stock", "Optimal Stock")),
        Department = "Luggage", IF(StockHoldingDays > 90, "Over Stock", IF(StockHoldingDays < 30, "Under Stock", "Optimal Stock")),
        Department = "Jewellery, Ladies Bags & Accessories", IF(StockHoldingDays > 120, "Over Stock", IF(StockHoldingDays < 60, "Under Stock", "Optimal Stock")),
        Department = "Toys", IF(StockHoldingDays > 150, "Over Stock", IF(StockHoldingDays < 60, "Under Stock", "Optimal Stock")),
        Department = "Sports & Fitness", IF(StockHoldingDays > 150, "Over Stock", IF(StockHoldingDays < 60, "Under Stock", "Optimal Stock")),
        Department = "Eye Wear", IF(StockHoldingDays > 270, "Over Stock", IF(StockHoldingDays < 120, "Under Stock", "Optimal Stock")),
        Department = "Blsh", IF(StockHoldingDays > 90, "Over Stock", IF(StockHoldingDays < 30, "Under Stock", "Optimal Stock")),
        Department = "Tenants", " ",
        ""
    )
)

How to use Measure as Slicer in Power BI

You can't. You will need to approach this differently.
Quickest way would be to create a Calculated Column with the above expression and then use that for your slicer.

Otherwise, create a single column table that will serve as your slicer with the values "Over Stock", "Under Stock", "Optimal Stock".
Then create a Measure similar to:
Slicer row count = 
  COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
      '3_month_sales_&_stock',
      [StockStatus] IN YourSlicerTable[SlicerColumn]
    )
  )

And add this new measure as visual filter to the visuals you want.

its appended data, that why i used the measure instead of column
